# how to encrypt foreign key in Django

Tags: django

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    u_v_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    u_middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    gender_list = (('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'))
    u_gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=gender_list)
    u_dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to user in above table...
How to encrypt it??

Comment: FKs are used so rows in tables can reference each other.  If you encrypt it, how will they find each other?  What are you *really* trying to do by encrypting it?

Comment: Most of the time, encrypting fields is pointless - if someone has access to your server, they more then likely have access to the key needed to decrypt the fields.

Answer (score -2):

What is the point to encrypt it? User here will show to another table where all the information is saved. So if you want to encrypt user data, encrypt the data you referring too and not the foreign key.

But also I would suggest to "hide" the data only the if it is really needed to be hidden. Passwords are encrypted by default if you using Django user system and the other information, like name or surname... If you're not building the Swiss Bank system, I don't know if you really need to "hide" such an info.

Maybe you have another idea when telling encrypting, if so, please describe it in more detailed way :)

Comment: Sorry, but downvote. While I agree with you that in **this case** encrypting the `ForeignKey` is unnecessary, because you can find out the user relation anyways when you know the user profile, the question itself is generally a good one and sometimes it makes sense to hide the relation an object has (example: hierarchical notes with a relation to the parent)